# Adding dynamically created columns and rows to listview wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm trying to add dynamic columns and dynamic rows to a listview. I just can't get why this is so freaking hard to do in wpf. So the story is as follows, I have the user select some tables from a SQL database, for instance Table: PgPoints and PgValuesDouble.
So the listview should display it's column headers as PgPoints and PgValuesDouble.

Next from the SQLDatabase the data is grabbed on the name of the selected tables (PgPoints and PgValuesDouble). This data is returned as a List.

I have the following C# code right now:

```
  public partial class Page3 : Page
{

    private List<string> columns = new List<string>();

    /*Variables passed through constructor*/
    private dbConnection connection;
    private List<string> selectedTables;


    public Page3(dbConnection connection, List<string> selectedTables)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.connection = connection;
        this.selectedTables = selectedTables;
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        gridView.Columns.Clear();

        //Loop through selected tables and add them as column names to listview
        foreach(string selectedTableNames in selectedTables)
        {
            GridViewColumn clm = new GridViewColumn();
            clm.Header = selectedTableNames;
            clm.Width = 100;
            gridView.Columns.Add(clm);

            //Loop through the data grabbed from the SQL database
            foreach (string columNames in connection.GetColumnsList(selectedTableNames))
            {
                columnListView.Items.Add(columNames);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;

        if (b.Equals(button_back))
        {
            NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
        else
        {
            //Go forward event here!
        }
    }
}
```

And XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="HCCSVExport.Pages.Page3"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HCCSVExport.Pages"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
  Title="Page3" MinWidth="519" MinHeight="321">

<Grid x:Name="grid" Background="White">
    <Button x:Name="button_next" Content="volgende" Margin="0,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="86.493"/>
    <Button x:Name="button_back" Content="vorige" Margin="0,0,101,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="89" Uid="button_back"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Selecteer de kolommen uit de tabellen" Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <ListView x:Name="columnListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="240" Margin="10,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="499">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="gridView"/>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

The result is that all the data that is grabbed from the SQL database is put in to both columns. How can I get the data that belongs to the PgPoints column under the PgPoints column and the data that belongs to the PgValuesDouble column under the PgValuesDouble column?

[Screenshot](http://afbeelding.im/fDTAd4ta)

As you can see the cells in both columns are the same instead of different cells for each column...

**EDIT:**

So i've changed to a datagrid which seems to work. But I really want a ListView to do the job :( i just don't get why it's so hard to do this in wpf kinda frustrating....

```
public partial class Page3 : Page
{

    /*Variables passed through constructor*/
    private dbConnection connection;
    private List<string> selectedTables;

    public Page3(dbConnection connection, List<string> selectedTables)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.connection = connection;
        this.selectedTables = selectedTables;
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = createDataTable().DefaultView;
    }

    private DataTable createDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        bool first = true;

        foreach (string selectedTableNames in selectedTables)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(selectedTableNames));

            List<string> tmpList = connection.GetColumnsList(selectedTableNames);

            for (int x = 0; x < tmpList.Count; x++)
            {
                if (first)
                {
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    row[selectedTableNames] = tmpList[x];
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                else
                {
                    DataRow row = dt.Rows[x];

                    if (row != null)
                    {
                        row[selectedTableNames] = tmpList[x];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row = dt.NewRow();
                        row[selectedTableNames] = tmpList[x];
                        dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    }


                }

                dt.AcceptChanges();
            }

            first = false;

            dt.AcceptChanges();


        }

        dt.AcceptChanges();
        return dt;
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;

        if (b.Equals(button_back))
        {
            NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
        else
        {
            //Go forward event here!
        }
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="HCCSVExport.Pages.Page3"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HCCSVExport.Pages"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
  Title="Page3" MinWidth="519" MinHeight="321">

<Grid x:Name="grid" Background="White">
    <Button x:Name="button_next" Content="volgende" Margin="0,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="86.493"/>
    <Button x:Name="button_back" Content="vorige" Margin="0,0,101,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="89" Uid="button_back"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Selecteer de kolommen uit de tabellen" Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="499" Height="240"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: is selectedTables a List<T> and is this method defined in the code behind?

Comment: Hi Hardgraf, I updated the codeview with the whole page class so it's'easier to read. As you can see selectedTables is a List<string>

Comment: It's unclear what are you trying to put in to rows. How many rows do you have and what data needs to be shown for instance in the **intersection** of row1 with col1, row1 with col2 etc.

Comment: Hi Ivan, The amount of rows shouldn't matter because it has to work dynamically. I'll upload a screenshot how it looks now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help, i am using a DataGrid instead of that ListView though:

In the ViewModel i am using a DataTable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

DataColumn timeStamp = new DataColumn();
timeStamp.ColumnName = "TimeStamp";
dt.Columns.Add(timeStamp);

//ading a new row
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
```

and populate it:

```
row[timeStamp] = "100.2";
```

and so on, you add many columns with their specific values.

After each columns count changing:

```
LogTable.Clear();
LogTable = null;
LogTable = dt;
```

Elegant, or not, it works just fine for me, and even when i add more than 20 columns dynamically, no glitches are present.

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="logDataGrid"
           AutoGenerateColumns="True"
           ItemsSource="{Binding LogTable, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

I've seen at some point an example with an ObservableCollection instead of that DataTable but it was just a lot of fancy code.

Comment: Hi Olaru thanks for your suggestion! But for a listview this doesn't work sadly :(